# How to add NAT interface as eth1 instead of eth0

Tags: vagrant

I have a box where the order of network interfaces matters. The firewall and certain services are explicitly bound to eth0 which is meant to be the actual network interface.

When we setup a test VM using Vagrant, that eth0 adapter becomes the NAT adapter. Now I can parameterize all references to eth0 in our Puppet modules but that would add quite a bit of complexity that I would like to avoid.

How can I configure Vagrant to add a private network on eth0 and the NAT adapter on eth1?

Comment: I actually have the same issue ... did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I ended up parameterizing my Puppet modules, so that my configuration can work with other interfaces when run by Vagrant.

Comment: Btw, re. "off topic" votes: Vagrant is a DEV tool, that's why I believe this is a valid question for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

eth0 is always NAT interface [according to Mitchell](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2915).
I know it's possible to rename interfaces in Linux, not sure if it's possible with Virtualbox.